# If P=NP, then NP = coNP. Why is this so?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

I read that if we assume that P = NP, then NP = coNP. I am unable to understand why this is so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to show that $P=coP$ (think about it). Now, if $P=NP$ then $coP=coNP$, so that $NP=P=coP=coNP$.

Comment: Does it work the other way around if P!=NP then coP!=coNP?

Comment: I think so, you can use the _same_ proof to prove: if $coP = coNP$ then $P=NP$.